# Notify users on Mac if Java is not installed

Tags: java, macos, deployment

I wonder if there is a way to notify the users on Mac that Java does not exist and open a download page?

It's possible on Windows using launch4j.

And no I don't want to use Java webstart because the idea is to convert it to .app using App Bundler.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is providing a `.app` that won't run a better experience than using Web Start? I'd consider bundling a private JVM if you really want to write a desktop Java app.

Comment: It's also to much trouble, setting up a webserver etc. I have bundled a JVM, but it increases the file-size by like 70-100 mb.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) website you'll see it supports Mac OS too.
In case of Launch4J, or any other Java launcher solution, it's not Java code that checks if JRE is present - it's C(++) - a native executable.

Comment: it supports doing .exe on Mac. Not doing .app on Mac.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mac OS, but I do know it has Linux or BSD kernel. So anything that would work for Linux should work for Mac, right? There are other (free) Java launchers, you can check them out. And if nothing works out get the source for Launch4J and create a launcher for Mac :-)